# Syncing git fork with local computer

Tags: git, github

Once I've forked a repo and modified a file within it locally on my computer... how do I push these changes off so that they are reflected on my Github account online.  In other words, how do I sync my modified directory on my local computer with the remote?

Here is what I tried:

1) `git clone URL`
(i.e., the URL on the Github copy from clipboard section)

2) Make a change to a file within the directory I just cloned (which is now on my local computer)

3) `git add .`

4) `git status` (the file shows up as modified, which is great)

5) `git pull` (but I get the message "Already up-to-date.")

Instead of #5, I also tried `git push origin master` but got "Everything up-to-date"

What's wrong?  The changes are not reflected on my Github repo online.

Comment: you need to commit your changes before pushing them, use 'git commit'

Comment: After step 3, you need to commit. I find this website very useful: https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1.

Comment: Please post your answers as answers, not as comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes that are done in the github folder have to be commited via `git commit -m "optional message"` first.

If you add new files you need to register them to git via `git add`.

To sync with a remote branch first pull all changes from the remote branch with `git pull` and then you can push with `git push`.